# TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Tags: type-conversion, python-3.4

Im using Python3.4 but this project was imported from Python2 and the function below is displaying error mentiond in the title.

```
def int_to_bytes(i,len):
   res = b""
   for j in range(len):
      res += chr(i%256)
      i = i>>8
   return res
```

I supposed to make a bytes value of result of chr() function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do this:

```
res += chr(i%256).encode('utf-8')
```

See also https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you. But so many issues poped out after correcting this i think i will switch to python2.